# Adding Breadcrumb Navigation to Pages

Tags: apex, visualforce, navigation

Can anyone help me how to create BreadCrumb in visual page. 
I have searched across, found this  [Creating bread crumb in salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=siteforce_breadcrumb_add.htm&type=0). Actually i don't understand form where to start with this article.

Please anyone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link is related to [community/site.com](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=build_your_site.htm&type=0) stuff, so you won't be able to use this technology in a Visualforce Page.

> You can use Community Builder or Force.com Sites to build out your
>   Salesforce organization with custom pages and apps.

Seems like there is no native solution for VF, so you need to build it your self like [others did](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000Ahp5IAC):

```
<span>
    <a href="{!fooId}">Foo</a> / <a href="/{!barId}">Bar</a>
</span>
```

Or switch to lightning where you have a [native solution](https://u2g-cprm-dm-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/componentReference/suite.app?page=lightning:breadcrumb):

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:breadcrumbs>
        <lightning:breadcrumb label="Parent Account" href="path/to/place/1"/>
        <lightning:breadcrumb label="Case" href="path/to/place/2"/>
    </lightning:breadcrumbs>
</aura:component>
```